# The name "Monsters" doesnt exist in the current context

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I am fairly new to programming and have run into a little problem, so sorry if its a really simple solution but im not getting it .So I'm  programming a really simple version of hearthstone for practice. I created a method which generates all 5 of the cards into an array and I'm trying to use that array to make a list which will act as the players decks. However, in the for loop that I'm trying to do this in the Monsters array says it doesn't exist in the current context?

```
//Generates monsters and magic cards
public static MonsterCard[] GenerateCards()
{
    MonsterCard[] Monsters = new MonsterCard[5];

    Monsters[0].Name = "Lizard King";
    Monsters[0].Attack = 4;
    Monsters[0].Health = 3;

    Monsters[1].Name = "Piggy";
    Monsters[1].Attack = 2;
    Monsters[1].Health = 1;

    Monsters[2].Name = "Great Drake";
    Monsters[2].Attack = 7;
    Monsters[2].Health = 5;

    Monsters[3].Name = "Bear";
    Monsters[3].Attack = 5;
    Monsters[3].Health = 3;

    Monsters[4].Name = "Lion";
    Monsters[4].Attack = 6;
    Monsters[4].Health = 4;

    return Monsters;
}
```

main():

```
int main(){
    int number;
    GenerateCards();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    //Player 1 deck
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        number = rnd.Next(0, 4);
        Player1.Deck[i] = Monsters[number]; //<-- this Monsters is where the problem comes
    }

}
```

Comment: Please remove all links and paste the actual code instead

Comment: `GenerateCard` returns `Monsters`, but you never catch them locally in `main()` ! Monster is local to `GenerateCards` and dies once the function finishes. `MonsterCard[] Monsters = GenerateCards;` in `main()` will save that problem since you `return Monsters` inside `GenerateCards`.

Comment: Learn about [scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GenerateCard` returns `Monsters`, but you never catch them locally in `main()`.

`Monster` is local to `GenerateCards()` and dies right when the function finishes executing.

```
int main(){
     // ..
     MonsterCard[] Monsters = GenerateCards();
     // ..
}
```

The above will solve that problem since you `return Monsters` from `GenerateCards()`, which has the values you are looking for inside `main()`.

Comment: Ohhh I see now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Still `Monsters` in main is a **different variable** than `Monsters` in GenerateCards, does not matter that both have the same name, they are still different.

Comment: @KyleKhalaf no, it actually is a reference to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move your `monsters` property into a global context.

That's because it is in the *scope* of another method, so that it's a local variable, only accessible from this method (and it only exists in this method).

An example:

```
void m1 ()
{
    int a;
    //a exists
    {
        int b;
        //a and b exist
    }
    //only a exists
}
//nothing exists

void m2 ()
{
    //still nothing exists
    int c;
    //Only c exists
}
```

Variables only exist in their enclosing *scope*. That means, if you define a variable outside of a method, it exists for all methods:

```
int a;
void m1 ()
{
    //a exists
}

void m2 ()
{
    //a still exists
}
```

To learn more about this, read through [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx).